# Tilemap bug in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, tile

I have a problem with my tilemap in unity.
I draw a map and when I play the game, I sometimes see a white line between 2 tiles.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: A game snapshot showing a vertical white line between two tiles]

Comment: I had this kind of issue before and solved it by painstakingly rearranging pixels in the source PNG for my tilesets so that every tile has another tile next to it when it's imported (just a small black dot is good enough): you can get that kind of lines when an edge of a tile has no other tile next to it in the source image. Also verify that the grid and unit size match the pixel size of your tiles, and compression is set to point / no filter.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is still the case, but in the past you had to set some settings correctly when using 2D (and tilemaps). I remember having this problem as well (for me the fix was setting compression to Point).

Make sure you are using the sprite shader and that your tilemap texture compression is set to Point.
You can also try to disable antialiasing in `Edit>Project Settings>Quality`.

See also https://forum.unity.com/threads/black-lines-on-the-edges-of-tiled-sprites.226919/ and https://forum.unity.com/threads/random-white-lines-in-between-tiles.282362/